# Getting started with an extention for alfresco (4.x)

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

So I've been looking into how one creates an extention/module for alfresco and I got a bit confused as to whether I need to use Alfresco SDK, Ant, Maven, etc.

I'll state my motivations, here's what I'm trying to achieve with the extension:

- **create a custom aspect that adds two properties** (called AttachmentType and ItemID, where AttachmentType describes a type(customer, task, project, etc.) and ItemID contains the name of an item of that type).
- **each of these 2 properties will have a html select element**(i.e. drop down selection menu), the AttachmentType will contain a static list of types. A type can be selected trough the select element and the module will then query a remote server (trough jquery json-rpc I'm planning) and that server will send back all the names(=ID's) of that particular AttachmentType (i.e. for customer send back a list of all the customers) then the user can select the right ID (i.e. customer) from the second html select belonging to the ItemId property.

With that done another program then can query alfresco share for a document of a particular AttachmentType and ItemID trough CMIS.

What should I use to achieve this? Is putting some files in an amp file I make enough to do this?
Should I use Maven for this? What about SDK & Ant?

Hope somebody can push me in the right direction. For example the things this [link](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/wabson/2010/02/25/adding-custom-aspect-support-in-alfresco-share/) describes, do I put those edited files in those directories within the amp so they overwrite the real files? Where do I add the html select & jquery code so it'll be added on alfresco pages with those properties visible?

Thank you for taking the time to read this and thank you so much if you'll answer ofc!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best advice is to get started with a maven setup. With the provided archetypes you'll be up and running quickly with the built-in jetty server and H2 database, so you won't have to sweat too much about getting things started.

I wont give you all the answers, but I can point you in the right direction and get you started.

First of all, get up and running with Maven, [read about the Maven SDK here](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/alfresco-docs/alfresco-lifecycle-aggregator/latest/index.html)

Make sure you have Java and Maven 3 installed. Then fire up the AMP Archetype, [instructions here](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/alfresco-docs/alfresco-lifecycle-aggregator/latest/archetypes/alfresco-amp-archetype/index.html). To clear it a bit up run this command:

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/archetype-catalog.xml -Dfilter=org.alfresco.maven.archetype:
>   Select number 1 (org.alfresco.maven.archetype:alfresco-amp-archetype)

Select the latest version of the SDK (option 3, 1.0.2)

Enter group id, f.x "org.your.company"

Enter artifact name, f.x "alfresco"

Verify the settings (press enter)

Now this will have created a complete project for you, ready to use.

Now you're good to go, fire it up ([see this page for more info](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/alfresco-docs/alfresco-lifecycle-aggregator/latest/archetypes/alfresco-amp-archetype/usage.html)):

> export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1G -XX:PermSize=300m"
>
> mvn integration-test -Pamp-to-war

This might take a while, it will download all your dependencies.

Now you're ready to get into the action and start coding.

The best way to learn about making a custom model, aspects etc could be to follow [the knowledge tutorial in the docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc/concepts/kb-getting-started-overview.html).

A better way would be to read Jeff Potts excellent tutorials over at http://ecmarchitect.com, he wrote an excellent [article about content modelling](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-content/content-article-2ed.pdf).

To give you some hints: 
You'll need to define a bean for your custom model. This could go in the module-context.xml located in "src/main/amp/config/alfresco/module/alfresco/".

The bean definition will point to your model xml file, where you'll need to define a namespace and your custom types, aspects etc. After this, it's a matter of making these types and aspects available to either share or the alfresco explorer.

I won't go too much more into details, Jeff Potts already explained it, way better than I could ever do - [specially in his article about content modelling.](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-content/content-article-2ed.pdf)

After you get comfortable with your maven setup, you simply use Maven to build you up a nice AMP, or even a complete war with your own changes merged into it that you could drop into Tomcat, jboss etc, but worry about deployment later :)

Best of luck!

Comment: ty so much! I actually already had found Jeff Potts's 55 pages pdf and already read some stuff in there ^_^ so it's good to hear that I'm looking in the right spot. Your explanation of getting started with maven looks nice, I'll setup maven as you instructed immediately!

Comment: a few changes for other people who will read and use this answer: `Select number 1 (org.alfresco.maven.archetype:alfresco-amp-archetype)` needs to be moved out of the code snippet to be clear that one has to "Type 1 and press enter, then..." and `mvn integration-test -Pamp-to-war` needs to be run only after you cd to the artifact name directory, in the example case `cd alfresco`, otherwise it wont find the pam.xml

Comment: There seems to be a minor mistake in the architect guide so for those confused by where to place some files as there are multiple alfresco/extension directories, this link here describes a working setup of the architect guide files and a naming correction 
https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/content-modeling/custom-content-model-problem-ecmarchitect-tutorial

I can not confirm it's working tho atm as I seem to have a problem probably caused by a earlier installed module, but the OP of the thread stated that it was working for him as you can read there and it's a recent post

Comment: To correct the above, it actually doesn't work but only because of 1 file missing/incorrectly placed see [link](http://www.fossoffice.com/en/2013/05/01/custom-types-and-aspects-in-alfresco-4-2-c/) after that go to page 19 and 24 of the ecmarchitect guide to let the web client display your created aspects and properties. good luck to everyone who might read this :)